# How do you know when a big project is good enough to make it version 1.0?

Tags: release-management, software-quality

If you have a big project, how do you know when it is time to be version 1.0?

Comment: This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, since it is subjective.

Comment: It depends on whether the project is open-source collaborative, whether the initial release of the project is likely to attract experts (who are more error-tolerant) or novices (who are easily discouraged by bugs or rough corners), or commercial. For commercial projects, you will need to hire "focus groups" to get initial feedback on your project (think like movie pre-screening).

Comment: y should i sign-up to another site when it works on this site?

Comment: @user464463: it's considered rude if you knowingly and repeatedly disregard the rule. Your question is actually off-topic for this stackoverflow, and should be asked in programmers.stackexchange.com, which is intended for subjective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any big project for an example: If it does what is it made for and it has not got many bugs, then it should be fine, but this depends on what you think and what other people post about it..

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way is to make a list of the requirements. Tick the list of requirements, one by one, as each of them are satisfactorily solved. Once all the important requirements are satisfactorily solved, and the product has a satisfactorily low amount of open bugs and is considered stable enough for the intended primary users of the system, then you might consider blessing it as 1.0. There is no hard and fast rule, but that should give some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If following proper software engineering practices you would have (among others) a requirements document.  Once the requirements of that document are met then you have version 1.0.  After that you support it with newer versions (to fix bugs, add features, etc) as needed.  There is much more to the whole process, but those are the basics.